# Thread - Enhanced for - java

Tags: java

I'm just asking if is thread-safe to use

I precise that "doSomething()" is thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

Thread safety depends on the Collection over which you are iterating, not the use of enhanced for.  If the Collection is synchronized or you are not modifying the Collection, it is Thread safe.  ArrayList<> is not synchronized by default.

Answer (score 1):

If `doSomething()` modifies the state of the `Component` instance (which it probably does, since it looks like it has no return value), then no, it's not thread safe. You'll have to take care of the thread safety yourself.

Comment: But I don't modify the state of the list, but a member of the list, so as doSomething() is thread-safe I don't see the problem.

Comment: @kaoziun I meant that you are responsible for making doSomething thread safe by yourself. If you are already doing that, you should be good.

Comment: Yes I have done it myself. Ok I understand, thanks :-)
If I don't remove or add element in the list outside of a static bloc ("static { ... }", and if the methods of the elements are thread-safe, it's thread-safe, isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry I have forget to do @Eran ... this comment will be removed

Answer (score 1):

It is not thread safe if it is possible that another can modify `compo` variable, or any element in `compo` variable. you can use `ImmutableList` to be sure that it is not modified.

Comment: "or any element in compo variable" Even if the element in compo variable got method which are thread-safe ?